# Extract timezone from ISO8601 date time string

Tags: java, time, datetime-format

How to extract time zone from ISO-8601 date string in Java 8.

e.g:

```
   String timestamp1 = "2014-02-15T01:02:03Z" ;
   String timestamp2 = "2017-10-27T16:22:27.605-05:30";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html):

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-10-27T16:22:27.605-05:30").getZone()
```

to get an instance of [ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

Alternatively you can use `getOffset()` to obtain [ZoneOffset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html),which is more handy if you need to access the timezone offset in a numeric form.