# Swift - Retrieve timezone from ISO8601 date string

Tags: swift

I have dates saved in a database in this format - "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ". For example,  "2018-05-17T11:15:00+0330". The time zone varies, it is in whatever user's local time zone is.

I want to retrieve and display the date like "May 17, 2018 11.15AM", keeping the date/time in the same time zone as it was saved. How can I do that?

I tried this.

```
let dateString = "2018-05-17T11:15:00+0330"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
//formatter.timeZone = ???
print(formatter.date(from: dateString))
```

But I get the Date object in local timezone and converting that to date string displays the date in my local timezone as well.

Is there anything like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216251/1373592, in Swift?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a little extension to `TimeZone` I just whipped up. You can use it to create a `TimeZone` from an ISO8601 date string. It will handle timezones in the string in the following formats:

- Z (for UTC time)
- +/-HH
- +/-HHmm
- +/-HH:mm

Here is the extension:

```
extension TimeZone {
    init?(iso8601: String) {
        let tz = iso8601.dropFirst(19) // remove yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss part
        if tz == "Z" {
            self.init(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        } else if tz.count == 3 { // assume +/-HH
            if let hour = Int(tz) {
                self.init(secondsFromGMT: hour * 3600)
                return
            }
        } else if tz.count == 5 { // assume +/-HHMM
            if let hour = Int(tz.dropLast(2)), let min = Int(tz.dropFirst(3)) {
                self.init(secondsFromGMT: (hour * 60 + min) * 60)
                return
            }
        } else if tz.count == 6 { // assime +/-HH:MM
            let parts = tz.components(separatedBy: ":")
            if parts.count == 2 {
                if let hour = Int(parts[0]), let min = Int(parts[1]) {
                    self.init(secondsFromGMT: (hour * 60 + min) * 60)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

And a test:

```
print(TimeZone(iso8601: "2018-05-17T11:15:00+0330"))
```

You can combine this parsing and formatting so the final result is in the original timezone.

```
let dateString = "2018-05-17T11:15:00+0330"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString), let tz = TimeZone(iso8601: dateString) {
    let newFmt = DateFormatter()
    newFmt.dateStyle = .medium
    newFmt.timeStyle = .short
    newFmt.timeZone = tz
    let newString = newFmt.string(from: date)
    print(newString)
}
```

Comment: I think this handles negative offsets improperly. E.g. "2020-01-01T09:15:00-02:15" yields -6300 seconds from GMT rather than -8100 because this code treats the hour component as negative but the minute component as positive.

Answer (score 5):

What you are really trying to do, is to ignore the time zone.

You can just strip off the last 5 characters from the date string, parse it in one format, and format it in another format:

```
let dateString = "2018-05-17T11:15:00+0330"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
let date = formatter.date(from: String(dateString.dropLast(5)))! // note the stripping off here
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy hh.mma"
print(formatter.string(from: date))
```

Note that you can't compare this date with other dates because you've stripped its time zone off.

Also, [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) is a similar library to JodaTime.

Comment: This gives the correct output for the final string but `date` is in the wrong timezone and if any comparisons to other dates are needed, you will get unexpected results.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, that's true. Added a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix to @rmaddy answer as his answer has a problem with negative offset specially minute component as @jjoelson mentioned

```
extension TimeZone {
    init?(iso8601: String) {
        let tz = iso8601.dropFirst(19) // remove yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss part
        if tz == "Z" {
            self.init(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        } else if tz.count == 3 { // assume +/-HH
            if let hour = Int(tz) {
                self.init(secondsFromGMT: hour * 3600)
                return
            }
        } else if tz.count == 5 { // assume +/-HHMM
            if let hour = Int(tz.dropLast(2)), var min = Int(tz.dropFirst(3)) {
                min = (hour < 0) ? -1 * min : min
                self.init(secondsFromGMT: (hour * 60 + min) * 60)
                return
            }
        } else if tz.count == 6 { // assime +/-HH:MM
            let parts = tz.components(separatedBy: ":")
            if parts.count == 2 {
                if let hour = Int(parts[0]), var min = Int(parts[1]) {
                    min = (hour < 0) ? -1 * min : min
                    self.init(secondsFromGMT: (hour * 60 + min) * 60)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers do not work on all types of ISO 8601 formatted strings.

These are the possible [ISO 8601 time zone formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators):

```
<time>Z
<time>±hh:mm
<time>±hhmm
<time>±hh
```

The following code handles all of these cases. Please note that it requires iOS 16 as a minimum for the Regex.

```
extension TimeZone {
    /// Pattern that grabs the time zone from iso8601 strings
    /// This needs to handle the following cases:
    /// `<time>Z`
    /// `<time>±hh`
    /// `<time>±hhmm`
    /// `<time>±hh:mm`
    /// See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators .
    private static let iso8601TzPattern = /T[\d:.,]+([\+±−-])(\d\d):?(\d\d)?$/
    
    /// Extracts the time zone from an iso8601 formatted date string.
    init?(iso8601: String) {
        if iso8601.hasSuffix("Z") { // Zulu (UTC)
            self.init(secondsFromGMT: 0)
            return
        }
        
        guard let matches = try? Self.iso8601TzPattern.firstMatch(in: iso8601),
              let hours = Int(matches.2) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        // offset from GMT in seconds
        var offset = hours * 3600
        
        if let minutesString = matches.3, let minutes = Int(minutesString) {
            offset += minutes * 60
        }
        
        // sign
        switch matches.1 {
        // minus sign and hyphen-minus (not the same)
        case "−", "-":
            offset = -offset
        case "±":
            if offset != 0 {
                // only allowed for zero offset
                return nil
            }
        default: break
        }
        
        self.init(secondsFromGMT: offset)
    }
}
```

And here are some tests to validate it:

```
class TimeZoneTests : XCTestCase {
    func testISO8601() {
        // valid time zones
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45+01"), TimeZone(hours: 1, minutes: 0))
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45+01:00"), TimeZone(hours: 1, minutes: 0))
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24+01:00"), TimeZone(hours: 1, minutes: 0))
        
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45+12:34"), TimeZone(hours: 12, minutes: 34))
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24+1234"), TimeZone(hours: 12, minutes: 34))
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24+12:34"), TimeZone(hours: 12, minutes: 34))
        
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45-12:34"), TimeZone(hours: -12, minutes: -34))
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24-1234"), TimeZone(hours: -12, minutes: -34))
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24-12:34"), TimeZone(hours: -12, minutes: -34))
        // minus sign instead of hyphen in the offset
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24−12:34"), TimeZone(hours: -12, minutes: -34))
        
        // Zulu (UTC)
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45Z"), TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0))
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24Z"), TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0))
        XCTAssertEqual(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24±00"), TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0))
        
        // no time zone
        XCTAssertNil(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21"))
        XCTAssertNil(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24"))
        
        // invalid
        XCTAssertNil(TimeZone(iso8601: "2019-10-21T08:40:45.24±01"))
    }
}

private extension TimeZone {
    init?(hours: Int, minutes: Int) {
        self.init(secondsFromGMT: (hours * 60 + minutes) * 60)
    }
}
```