# Get time from timestamp string that includes timezone

Tags: swift, date, time, timezone, dateformatter

I receive a date

```
let slotDateString: String =  "2023-12-06T15:45:00+04:00"
```

I have two formatters:

```
var iso8601FormatterWithFullTimeZone: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter(withFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ")
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = .current

    return formatter
}

var hoursMinutesFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter(withFormat: "HH:mm")
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = .current

    return formatter
}
```

When I run the following code:

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = .iso8601FormatterWithFullTimeZone
let hoursMinutesFormatter: DateFormatter = .hoursMinutesFormatter

guard let slotDate: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: slotDateString) else {
     return
}

let slotHour: String = hoursMinutesFormatter.string(from: slotDate)
```

The `slotDate` returns me `2023-12-06 12:45:00 +0000`and
the `slotHour` returns me `"12:45"`

I live in timezone +01:00, but I want to get a date and an hour that take into account offset given in the original string.
So `slotDate` should have value of something like
`2023-12-06 15:45:00 +4000` or `2023-12-06 12:45:00 +0100`
and
`slotHour` should have exactly `"15:45"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop the timezone part and then get the hour:

```
let slotDateString = String("2023-12-06T15:45:00+01:00".dropLast(6)) //  Drop timezone from the string
var iso8601FormatterWithFullTimeZone: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter(withFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") //  No timezone in the formatter
    ,,,
}
```

So the `slotHour` would be exactly `"15:45"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a specific output from your Date object you need to use a second formatter for the output

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime]
formatter.timeZone = .current // <-- Same as yours, +1

let output = formatter.string(from: slotDate)
print(output)
```

> 2023-12-06T12:45:00+01:00

And to get the hour/minute string in the original time zone you need to use that time zone in your formatter

```
var hoursMinutesFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 4*3600) // Or use an identifier/abbrevation init if you know the zone 
    return formatter
}

let slotHour = hoursMinutesFormatter.string(from: slotDate)
print(slotHour)
```

> 15:45

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The problem is I don't know the timezone that I will have in dateString I receive so I can't just write 4*3600
The only way would be to extract number of offset hours from dateString?

Comment: Yes, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384494/swift-retrieve-timezone-from-iso8601-date-string

Comment: Not sure why this answer is upvoted since it only works if you know ahead of time what timezone the string represents. And based on the OP's comment, that isn't the case.

Comment: @HangarRash as you say, that information was given in a comment and I have given a link to another question as a response to that comment. The main point with my answer is that OP needs custom formatters also when generating the output and not only when parsing the original string.

Answer (score 0):

You say "...I want to get a date and an hour that take into account offset given in the original string." I don't think there is an easy way to extract the time zone from a date string using a DateFormatter.

If you know it's going to be in ISO8601DateFormatter .withInternetDateTime format, you could write code to extract the offset from UDT yourself, and then apply that timezone to your output date formatter before converting your date to a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same HH:mm for the same timezone then simply access the value from the original string. No date formatters are needed in this case.

```
let slotDateString: String =  "2023-12-06T15:45:00+04:00"
let slotHour = String(slotDateString.dropLast(9).dropFirst(11))
```

This works as long as `slotDateString` is in the format you show in your question and as long as you want the time is the same timezone of the original string and not the user's current timezone.